# Show that the Volume of the set $A=\left\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R} \times [0,\infty) ; 0<y<f(x)\right\}$ is $1$

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, multivariable-calculus

**QUESTION**
Show that the Volume of the set $A=\left\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R} \times [0,\infty) ; 0<y<f(x)\right\}$ is $1$
OR
Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow [0,\infty)$ a density function and Let $A=\left\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R} \times [0,\infty) ; 0<y<f(x)\right\}$  show that $Vol(A)=1$

I have no idea about how the Volume of a set works, It would be great if anyone can help me. This is the definition of $Vol(A)$ I'm working with $$Vol(A)=\int\cdots\int \textbf 1_A(x_1,\ldots,x_n)dx_1\ldots dx_n$$

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken (disclaimer: I have no familiarity with measure theory beyond undergraduate-level probability), the "volume" of a two-dimensional set is the area of the set. Volume is sometimes used interchangeably with measure.

Comment: @user170231 would you please give me a hint?

Comment: Use the fact that the indicator function $1_A(x, y)$ is $1$ if and only if $0 < y < f(x)$ to rewrite the double integral into the single integral $\int_{\mathbb R} f(x) dx$, which is equal to $1$ since $f$ is a probability density function. (I assume your $F$ is meant to be $f$, otherwise we need more information)

Comment: @Rushy thanks a lot! But, why is it valid to change the double integral to just the integral of the density function? I had that idea but I wasn't sure why.

Comment: You can probably use Tonelli's theorem together with $1_A$ being a non-negative measurable function, although there are probably easier ways (my analysis is a bit rusty)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align*}
{\rm Vol}(A)&=\int_{{\mathbb R} \times [0,\infty)}{\bf 1}_{A}(x,y){\rm Vol}({\rm d}(xy)) \\
&=\int_{{\mathbb R}}\int_{0}^{\infty}{\bf 1}_{A}(x,y){\rm Vol}({\rm d}y){\rm Vol}({\rm d}x) \\
&=\int_{{\mathbb R}}\int_{0}^{\infty}{\bf 1}_{(0,f(x))}(y){\rm Vol}({\rm d}y){\rm Vol}({\rm d}x) \\
&=\int_{{\mathbb R}}{\rm Vol}((0,f(x))){\rm Vol}({\rm d}x) \\
&=\int_{{\mathbb R}}f(x){\rm Vol}({\rm d}x) \\
&=1.
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
{\bf 1}_{A}(x,y)&=
\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
1, & (x,y) \in A \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{array}
\right. \\
&=
\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
1, & 0<y<f(x) \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{array}
\right. \\
&=
\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
1, & y \in (0,f(x)) \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{array}
\right. \\
&={\bf 1}_{(0,f(x))}(y).
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks a lot! But I have one question... What happens between the second and third line? (When we change $1_{A}(x,y)$ to $1_{A}(0.f(x))(y)$). I'm just started with integrals in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, I will really appreciate it!

Comment: The proof was added.